# Site has a width limit even if not set

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive

I have finished my home site and want it to be responsive, I want that the content takes the full page width, but the width somehow has a limit, so when I want to make the text bigger, it will just break at a certain width (see screenshot for example).

Here's an example:

```scss
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background: #000000 !important;
    }

.container {
    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
}
```

The `h1` is originally 2em, but when making it bigger (3em), the text will break because of the width limit and not expand itself in the width.

Why is the content not centered on resizing? Since the content has `display:flex` with `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center`.

Here's my full code:

```css
:root {
  --animate-delay: 0.5s;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e141b;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace;
}

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  color: white;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.container .intro {
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.container .intro p a {
  color: #61dafb;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container .skills {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.container .skills h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 60%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar {
  margin: 1.2rem 0;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .info {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .info span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line {
  height: 0.6em;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: #1f5bc4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1f5bc4;
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #fbfbfb;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.python span {
  width: 70%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.python span::after {
  content: "70%";
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.php span {
  width: 40%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.php span::after {
  content: "40%";
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.html span {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.html span::after {
  content: "100%";
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.css span {
  width: 90%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.css span::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.javascript span {
  width: 80%;
}

.container .skills .skill-bars .bar .progress-line.javascript span::after {
  content: "80%";
}

.container .services {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.container .services ul {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 2rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .services ul li {
  display: flex;
  width: 29em;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  align-self: start;
}

.container .services ul li h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

.container .services ul li .service {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 10em;
}

.container .services ul li .service i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.container .services ul li .qual {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  min-height: 7em;
  max-height: 7em;
}

.container .services ul li .qual i {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.container .services p a {
  color: #61dafb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .services p a:hover {
  color: #80def8;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn">Welcome to shard's website </h1>
    <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__delay-1s">
      Hey! I'm Léon, a passionate 17y old developer & cybersecurity student! I'm always working on a few projects, looking for new opportunities.
    </p>
    <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__delay-2s">
      <a href="/projects">See current projects</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="skills animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__delay-3s">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <p>
      My skills are in constant evolution, I'm always learning new things and improving in programming & cybersecurity. I'm open to any kind of project, feel free to contact me, I'll be happy to be part of it!
    </p>
    <div class="skill-bars">
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>Python</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line python">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line php">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line html">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>CSS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line css">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>JavaScript</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line javascript">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>You can also check things I've created on my github or on the project page.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="services animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__delay-4s">
    <h2 id="title">Services</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="service">
          <h3>Web Development</h3>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-file"></i> Single Page Applications</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> User/Admin panels</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i> Authentication & Authorization</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i> API Development</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="service">
          <h3>Everything Else</h3>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i> Scripting Services, Python, JavaScript, TypeScript</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-database"></i> Database Creation & Management</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-robot"></i> Automation</div>
          <div><i class="fa-brands fa-monero"></i> Paywalls & Crypto Paywalls</div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i> Custom Requests</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="qual">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user-secret"></i>
          <div>
            <h3>Support for Anonimity</h3>
            <p>
              I accept anonymous payment methods, such as ETH and XMR.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="qual">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-face-smile-beam"></i>
          <div>
            <h3>Effective Cooperation</h3>
            <p>
              My cooperation with my clients make us feel like a team rather than a job. I revise and refactor until complete satisfaction is met.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="qual">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-hourglass-half"></i>
          <div>
            <h3>On Time Completion</h3>
            <p>
              I make sure that the job is done in time. I don't like to keep my clients waiting.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="qual">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
          <div>
            <h3>Minimalism & simplicity</h3>
            <p>
              Minimalism and simplicity yields results that satisfy both the end user(s) and the client.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      You can contact me trough my <a href="mailto:sh7user@gmail.com">Mail</a>, <a href="https://t.me/sh7user">Discord</a> or <a href="">Telegram</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

Comment: Many of the reasons why the code isn't behaving as you intended are due to the way you wrote the HTML code, which is not included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.conatiner` class is working and the contents are center aligned but the text in `h1` and below `h1` are taking full width.
FYI, flex box will show effects only if the children elements are not of same width as flex container

In your example above, I guess the flex container is working as expected because when the `.intro` width is smaller than `.container` then flex-box shows its effect.

class `.intro` is taking same width as `.container` class thus they don't align in center.

you should use `text-align: center` to align text content in center for your desired screen size.

Comment: Thanks! This is a valuable information, I'll take note.

Comment: I had problems with my footer thas isn't in that code, I discovered the problem and fixed it!